# What is the recommended way to create a database per client with Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sharding

I will try to explain my question with an example:
let's say that I have a client, a cellular company. I need to create a database which includes data such as - customer lists, accounts, payment options and so on.
Now I have another client - another cellular company, but of course - the skeleton database will be identical to the first client.

How can I create a database that would include information of all the companies (clients), on the other, each company (client) will have its own database?

I hope that the question is understandable, I'd love some help.

Comment: Not exactly sure if you're asking about actual database instance allocation, or more about your app's database design in general. If it's the latter, that would be off-topic, since it's fairly broad. If it's the former, maybe refine the question a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at Azure Sql Database Elastic Scale ?

You can find more information here : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction/

The elastic tools library is designed for this kind of workload.

Hope this helps

Julien

Answer (score 3):

In addition, also please see [Elastic Database Pools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool/). The Elastic Scale features provide the tools to create a single application in which each customer received their own database and Elastic Data Pools provides the mechanism to share resource between such databases to reduce costs.

Comment: I went to the Azure Data Camp few weeks ago this is exactly what was recommended. And if you have a customer from the pool that requires too many DTUs, then move it out of the pool.